# Lenvo B450 won't boot on battery only?

Tags: laptop, battery

We bought a Lenovo B450 laptop almost a year ago. It comes with a NVIDIA GEFORCE with CUDA graphics and so the battery life is terrible. It will only last 1:30 hours max.

We try to run it on battery as much as possible but because the battery life is short sometimes we can't notice that the battery is so low until the computer blacks out.

Because of the short battery life, the laptop is always plugged on AC power. One night the computer froze. Because it was already late, I just reset the laptop my pressing the power button for 10 seconds. The laptop shut off but I did not bother restarting it.

The next morning, the laptop won't turn on on battery only. It will only turn on on AC power. The computer instantly shuts down(improperly) once the adapter is removed. But the battery was at 100% then. Now it is slowly losing charge (currently at 74%). The battery indicator says, "Plugged in, not charging".

I want to bring the laptop to school but I can't because it won't be portable at all.

Just to summarize it all:

```
1) The laptop suffered some blackouts already.
2) The laptop was on AC power most of the time.
3) When the computer froze, it was reset (hard shutdown).
4) The laptop won't boot with battery only since then.
5) The laptop will shutdown instantly when AC adapter is removed.
6) The battery won't charge and is gradually losing charge.
```

======================= UPDATE =============================

We got the battery replaced. Unfortunately, it delivers only 2 hours max of power.

Comment: I think the battery life is going to end . If you think it is stil on warrenty, you should contact the vendor for battery replacement. Or you may get a new battery yourself. Anyway, I just wonder of that max 1.5 hr last battery ...

Comment: I believe it still on warranty but I am not sure if the battery is covered by it. And what about the battery life?

Comment: You should try on-the-spot . So bring over your laptop to Service Centre. analysis the fault whether it js tje battery itself or else.

Comment: what os? i've had experience with thinkpad batteries going bad post linux install on two seperate systems

Comment: The battery is dead.  (Using the laptop on battery as much as possible is a bad idea.)

Comment: What if they tell us to leave the laptop to them and they will just fix it? I can't just leave it there, I don't trust those guys. That is why I posted this here so that those who know can assure me that this is a specific problem and has a specific solution so that I can just go there and say, "Hey I need a replacement of this".

Comment: The laptop dual boots linux and windows. Both are reporting the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a Dell Inspiron which did the same thing. Instead of the battery only holding less and less times until nothing, it stopped working overnight. Went from maybe 15-30 minutes to 0. We now have to use the power cord and turn the computer off all the time (no more sleep for transportation).

As you said

> We try to run it on battery as much as possible

I guess it's just considered dead by the laptop after a year of use.

Comment: Editorial note: that's pretty smart to make laptop to behave like that. I didn't buy a second battery for my 5-6 year old laptop which still has enough power to sleep for a day (or run for 10 minutes...).

Comment: I am thinking of getting a replacement battery. It is odd though, that most posts about a dead battery says that the battery life span gradually became shorter before the battery died completely. In my case, it was sudden. From 1.5hrs runtime to dead(i believe).

Comment: 1.5h to nothing sure is a big gap... It would seem more probable that something broke. Costs nothing to ask for applying the warranty to this.

Comment: We had it serviced in a shop. The techie confirmed it was a dead battery.

Answer (score 0):

The batter is dead. And just for purpose of sharing my experience, freezing the battery didn't even return any juice.